# Github website "Clone or Download" button not working on firefox

Tags: firefox, github

I am using `firefox version 49.0.1`. Now for every github repository the button "Clone or download" doesn't work.

I checked the console it shows this

[image]

- The first two lines are printed in console whenever I access any page of github.com and the 3rd line when I click the green **"clone or download"** button.
- Also the small door like option by which we logout of github doesn't work.

(Why old version of firefox? )  Because it's provide a feature (small UI related thing which bugs me in latest version)

It was working few days ago.

---

#### Solved

Github resolved it on May 9-10 2017.

Comment: I can reproduce what you found with Firefox 45 (ESR). You may want to ask your support contact at GitHub to fix this bug. Btw. I would suggest to you to use Firefox ESR to get security support if you can not upgrade: https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/organizations/all/#builds

Comment: @JanZerebecki.: Well that means the problem is not unique to me. It is happening to everyone using the older version? Let's check esr. Btw you know it was working few days back...just suddenly how can this happen? Without any further update or anything? (And why the DV?   )

Comment: I too got the same issue today, `Version: 45.9.0esr-1~deb8u1`

Comment: @coderredoc GitHub makes updates multiple times per day. Everyone makes errors. Did you contact them? What did they say?

Comment: @JanZerebecki.: No I didn't...I will soon...getting less time and busy too. :(

Comment: @JanZerebecki.: It is reported..they will look into the matter.

Comment: Same issue for me, in Firefox 50.1.0, and also in a different version on my work machine.

Comment: @JanZerebecki.: It is resolved now...Really they did it so efficiently and promptly. I am impressed.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a workaround:

1. go to `about:config`
2. find the entry `security.csp.enable`
3. double-click that row to set the `Value` to `false`

Obviously, this might impact safety in horrible ways, but at least I can continue working.